# Trying to recover a deleted ODT file

Tags: data-recovery

I'd tried using Photorec to restore a deleted ODT file since I accidentally deleted an important part of the boot files.  Sadly, the option for filtering file searches for ODT's exclusively isn't listed.  Any advice?

Comment: You need to create your own custom extension to recover any type of file that is not listed.  See https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec

Comment: Is there a better program than Photorec?  It shouldn't be this hard to run a program like this.  Having to code things in like this isn't how programs should be made.

Comment: try using testdisk

Comment: As far as live CD's go which ones would you recommend that can find ODT files?

Comment: You can use the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu with and install testdisk with `sudo apt install testdisk`. The testdisk package contains the PhotoRec program.